# Component not getting destroyed when navigating to different route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component which has a subscription in `ngOnInit()` method, when i navigate to different route i still see the component being alive in the `heap snapshot`.

**Component A**

```
sub: Subscription 
this.sub = this.detect.isValid().subscribe(data => this.data = data);

ngOnDestroy(){
   this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Component B**

Component A is still alive, when i move to Component B route, but **if i comment the subscription** `(this.sub)` ... the component is no longer visible **(getting destroyed)**

I am not sure why the component is not getting destroyed even when i am unsubscribing the observable?

```
this.sub.unsubscribe();
```

Below is the code for `detectService`

```
private $value: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

constructor() {
   this.$value = new BehaviorSubject(true);
}
public isValid(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.$value;
}
```

Comment: Can you check whether ngOnDestroy hook getting called or not?

Comment: Its not getting called, do you see any reason behind it?

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing full code, Can you create stack blitz?